# Zend Rest Server is not reading protected object variables

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework and I am working on REST web service API. While my model output is protected object variables `Zend_Rest_Server()`. It is unable to handle that and throw an error.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Webservices_Models_Token Object
        (
            [_id:protected] => 1
            [_token_key:protected] => 123
            [_mapper:protected] => 
        )
)
```

While why model is returning above result, I am getting error. I got this result from zend model mapper.

> Oh Dear!
>
> You seem to have arrived here by error, or the page you are seeking
>   has been removed and can no longer be displayed.
>
> Perhaps you are looking for a page that has been moved during the
>   recent improvements to our website. An error occurred ** This needs to
>   be altered before go live Exception information:
>
> Message: Invalid Character Error

Bellow output works fine and generating xml from `$this->_server = new Zend_Rest_Server()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [token_key] => 123
        )
)
```

Can anyone tell me whats the problem?
How can I solve it?

Comment: I'd like to see the model but I suspect you need to implement `__get()` and perhaps `__toString()` and `toArray()`

Comment: @RockyFord:You exactly correct toArray saves me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is did the trick for me. **toArray()**

```
  $select  =  $this->getDbTable()->select()->where($where);
  return $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
```

Thanks.